# php-Zendframework does full-text-search only for a number of files

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, full-text-search

I'm using php-Zendframework for full text searching in some pdf documents. I include them in the following way :

```
ini_set('include_path', '/var/www/html/php-ZendFramework-1.10.6-1.fc14.src/ZendFramework-1.10.6/library');
require_once('/var/www/html/php-ZendFramework-1.10.6-1.fc14.src/ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Search/Lucene.php');
require_once('/var/www/html/php-ZendFramework-1.10.6-1.fc14.src/ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Pdf.php');
```

After this, for every pdf I have, I'm applying the following code in a loop:

```
if(strcmp(strtolower($link),"pdf")==0){
    $fileName = '/var/www/html/tmp/'.$id.'.'.$link;
    $result = pdf2text ($fileName);
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create('/var/www/html/tmpindex');
    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('path', '/var/www/html/tmpindex'));
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('contents', $result,'utf-8'));
    $index->addDocument($doc);
    $index->commit();
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open('/var/www/html/tmpindex');
    $write = 1;

    if ((sizeof($hits)<=0) && ($h == 0))
        $write = 0;

    for($h=0;$h<sizeof($givenwords);$h++){
        $hits = $index->find('contents:' . $givenwords[$h]);
        if ($h != 0){

            if (strcmp(strtolower($conditions[$h-1]),"and") == 0)
                $write = ($write && (sizeof($hits)>0) );
            else if (strcmp(strtolower($conditions[$h-1]),"or") == 0)
                $write = ($write || (sizeof($hits)>0) );
            else
                $write = ($write && (sizeof($hits)<=0) );

        }
     }
     $removePath = '/var/www/html/tmpindex';
     $hits = $index->find('path:' . $removePath);
     foreach ($hits as $hit) {
         $index->delete($hit->id);
     }
}
```

However, after some files are searched (which returns correct results) it stops searching the following files. In the error.log file the following php notice appears:

```
iconv():Detected an illegal character in input string in /var/www/html/php-ZendFramework-1.10.6-1.fc14.src/ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Search/Lucene/Analysis/Analyzer/common/Text.php on line 58
```

My question is :
How to apply a code which tells that :

```
if (file cannot be read) wrtite_the_cause and skip to search other files;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think try..catch should do the trick for you. Just wrap your code.